# Visual Studio 2010 Local Variable History

Tags: visual-studio-2010, history

I'm working on debugging a process which has a number of nested loops which change a couple different local variables.

I can watch these by just stepping through...one iteration at a time, but it's quite tedious, and I'm losing track of my place. I simply don't have time to write down each variable, every single time.

Is there a way that I can see the history of a local variable? A plugin? Any ideas if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about logging the variables inside the loop with [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) or [`Trace.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/149a051x.aspx)? Then you can inspect the results afterwards.

If you're only interested in the values at certain points in a run, you could make the logging dependent on a Boolean variable's value, toggling it on and off manually in the debugger.

Comment: This should work. I'm not sure I understand the different between Debug.WriteLine and Trace.WriteLine. I'm new to C# and VS10.

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` will only produce any output in Debug builds, so that's your best bet (and won't have any performance impact on release builds if you decide to leave them in). `Trace.WriteLine` generates content for consumption by any listeners that are attached -- essentially the same thing but intended for release builds.

Comment: Note also that you can set *conditional* breakpoints, so they're only triggered if the variables you're interested in are in a particular state or have changed.

Answer (score 2):

May not be helpful in your case, but [Debugger Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/debuggercanvas.aspx) is pretty neat. It visually shows you the call-chain and allows you to "get an overview over recursive calls by showing one bubble per invocation"... check it out :)

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll probably accept the other answer, but this is going to be helpful in the future, so I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Is there a version for Premium?

Comment: It looks like that's a negative (because it does code reuse with an Ultimate only feature). That's really unfortunate... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2011/06/13/debugger-canvas-available-for-download.aspx